# Android Api question

Tags: android

Does anyone know what api level was the telephony manager class put in android. Also, when was the the newest SMS class (the old one was deprecated) put in?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this [Telephony Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) ?
That's in there from API lvl 1, although some parts are added in later versions. The linked page tells you from which API lvl each part is btw.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I must be blind though bc I've looked at those pages all the time and never noticed the api's levels being there until you pointed it out.

Comment: The first is quite noticable, but the others next to each member is almost greyed out... A bit of a design-miss I guess :D